# swift 2.1 cannot convert value of type anyobject to expected argument type nslayoutconstraint

Tags: ios, swift, syntax-error

Now i am working on swift 2.1 but i have create my project on swift 2.0 , my code is working on swift 2.0 but when i try to code convert in latest swift i cant able to understand how to convert please give me solution

```
   var header_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var header_constraint_V_Format = ""
            var bubble_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var bubble_constraint_V_Format = ""
            var content_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var content_constraint_V_Format = ""


            if message?.role == Role.Sender {
                header_constraint_H_Format =  "[header(50)]-5-|"
                header_constraint_V_Format =  "V:|-5-[header(50)]"
                bubble_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-(>=5)-[bubble]-10-[header]"
                bubble_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|-5-[bubble(>=50)]-5-|"
                content_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-(>=5)-[content]-25-|"
                content_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|[content]-5-|"
            } else {
                header_constraint_H_Format =  "|-5-[header(50)]"
                header_constraint_V_Format =  "V:|-5-[header(50)]"
                bubble_constraint_H_Format  =  "[header]-10-[bubble]-(>=5)-|"
                bubble_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|-5-[bubble(>=50)]-5-|"
                content_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-25-[content]-(>=5)-|"
                content_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|[content]-5-|"
            }


            let header_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(header_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let header_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(header_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            let bubble_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(bubble_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let bubble_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(bubble_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            let content_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(content_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let content_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(content_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            self.contentView.addConstraints(header_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(header_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(bubble_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(bubble_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
            self.bubbleImgView.addConstraints(content_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
            self.bubbleImgView.addConstraints(content_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `UIView` method `.addConstraints` take type `NSLayoutConstraint`, not type `AnyObject`

```
UIView Class Reference:
func addConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint)
```

Since you cast your `NSLayoutConstraint` properties to `AnyObject` in your call to `.addConstraints(...)`, your try to invoke the latter using an invalid argument type.

Try removing the `as [AnyObject]` in your call to `.addConstraints(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`func addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` is expect parameter of array of `NSLayoutConstraint`. So it does not make sense add [AnyObject].

So instead of setting type NSArray, do it [NSLayoutConstraint] or simply remove it.

```
let header_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(header_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

self.contentView.addConstraints(header_constraint_H)
```